# what is the maximum value of $e^{\sin x }/ e^{\cos x}$ where $x$ is a real number?

Tags: calculus

For this I did the differentiation and I got $e^{(\sin x-\cos x)} (\cos x+\sin x)$. Now I equated it to $0$ and got $\tan x=-1$. Now, how to proceed further ?

Comment: Please format your expression. It is unclear what the exponent is.

Comment: Which values of $x$ have a tangent of $-1$? Try $x=-\pi/4$, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution given by @lab bhattacharjee is very nice. I'm explaining little bit further.

Given : $$\dfrac{e^{\sin (x)}}{e^{\cos (x)}}=e^{\sin (x)-\cos (x)}$$

$$=e^{\sqrt{2}\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin (x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos (x)\}}$$

$$=e^{\sqrt{2}\{\cos (\frac{\pi}{4})\sin (x)-\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})\cos (x)\}}$$

$$=e^{\sqrt{2}\{\sin (x-\frac{\pi}{4})\}}$$

$\text{When $x = \frac{3 \pi}{4}$,  $\implies$ $\sin (x-\frac{\pi}{4})$ }$$=$ $\sin (\frac{3 \pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4})$$=$ $\sin (\frac{ \pi}{2})$$=1$.

Therefore, Maximum value is $e^{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{e^{\sin x}}{e^{\cos x}}=e^{\sin x-\cos x}$$

Now $e^{\sin x-\cos x}$ will attain maximum iff $\sin x-\cos x$ does so.

Now $\sin x-\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)$ 
and $-1\le\sin\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)\le1$

If you need calculus, set $f(x)=\sin x-\cos x$ and use  [Second Derivative Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html)

Comment: If I have to do second derivative test on f(x)=sinx-cosx only so then what's the use of changing it into √2sin(x−π/4) and then f''(x) =cosx-sinx , so now how can I conclude what's the maximum value ?

Comment: the plot http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+exp%28sin+x-cos+x%29 could help you to see

Comment: Sir , actually I am not good with graphs right now ,so can you please explain in layman terms how to proceed with this ques .

Comment: Knowg the sine function, I think  the second derivative test is a bit… redundant.

Comment: @Bernard, In case the usage of calculus is mandatory

Comment: @Iab bhattacharjee: Do you think there are  teachers with a so tortured mind that they would ask to forget  all about sines except their derivatives?